# Using a DocumentTermMatrix with a neural net classifier to make predictions in R

Tags: r, neural-network, text-processing, naivebayes

I have been trying to learn how to use a DocumentTermMatrix to make predictions in R.
I have been using the following link as a reference to try and make predictions for a different dataset.

https://rpubs.com/cen0te/naivebayes-sentimentpolarity

Here, the author uses an IMDB movie review dataset where the review text is analysed. Predictions are then made based on the review text as to whether the review is positive or negative using the Naive Bayes classifier (from e1071). The dataset contains a separate column with yes/no values where if a review was positive, the value is 'yes' else it is 'no'.

I have successfully implemented this for the Naive Bayes classifier on a different dataset however I now want to use different classifiers to do this so I can compare their performance.

I have been trying to use the neural net classifier (from the neuralnet package) however I do not know where to begin.

For the Naive Bayes classifier the following code was used to make predictions:

```
classifier <- naiveBayes(train_DocumentTermMatrix, input_training_data$class, laplace = 1)
pred <- predict(classifier, test_DocumentTermMatrix)
```

For the neural net package, I require a formula to run the classifier however I want to make predictions based on the document term matrix so I am confused as to what the formula is.

How can I proceed with this?